# Is is possible to create a new TypeScript interface of array types from an existing interface of non-array types?

Tags: typescript, interface, extends

I have [something akin to] this:

```
type Thunk = 'uh' | 'um' | 'dunno mate';
interface Whatever {
    meh: Thunk;
}
```

And that's all good my bro. But then later I need this:

```
interface LoadsOfWhatever {
    meh: Thunk[];
}
```

Is there a way to extend/Pick/etc it from `Whatever` or will this just need to be literally created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). These let you calculate a new type from an old one, applying some transformation to every property. Here's how it looks to turn every property into an array:

```
type Thunk = 'uh' | 'um' | 'dunno mate';
interface Whatever {
    meh: Thunk;
}

type LoadsOfWhatever = {
  [key in keyof Whatever]: Whatever[key][];
}
```

Obviously it's wordier than the original code if all you have is the one `meh` property. But if `Whatever` had 50 properties, you wouldn't need to change `LoadsOfWhatever`; it would turn all 50 properties into arrays

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgVwHYGsoF4oHIFy1AH2wQFt8isATZJAeyhIENgIsBuAKAEskWAnAGaMAxtADqcZhABuEPlADeHKCoYQ4ALliJUnAL4cOoSFAAytRpQDOAeQESps%20ZiUqA2igggoPKJ5C0AlAOLE4AulohMnIeXmFuYfpAA)